# Error accessing cookies at middleware.ts (Next.js 13)

Tags: javascript, cookies, middleware, next.js13

I'm having trouble accessing the cookies at the middleware.ts of my next.js app. I don't know why it fails if I have another next.js app with the same structure and it works, I suppose that becase the other app uses Next.js 14. Whenever I navigate through my app and make the middleware available, I get this error: `Error: Invariant: cookies() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.`

this is my middleware.ts:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
 
// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const jwt = cookieStore.get("zurii-hr-panel-token")?.value || "";
  const origin = request.nextUrl.clone().origin;
  
  if(jwt) {
    const decoded = jwtDecode(jwt);
    const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const validateJWT = decoded.exp && decoded.exp > currentTimestamp;
    if (validateJWT) {
      if(request.nextUrl.pathname==="/login") {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/collaborators`);
      }
      return NextResponse.next();
    } else if(!validateJWT && request.nextUrl.pathname!=="/login") {
      return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/login`);
    }
  } else if(!jwt && request.nextUrl.pathname!=="/login") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/login`);
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/login", "/collaborators", "/settings", "/status"]
}
```

I don't know what to do and I've been stuck for ages with this problem.